# How to detect objects within a radius without using a trigger collider?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I want an object to run code that detects objects around them, in a specific radius.

BUT I cannot use a trigger... or any game objects or components on the objects I'm trying to detect.

What could I do just using code?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145662/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-johnson-how-to-detect-objects-within-a-radius-wit); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

The classes [`Physics`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) and [`Physics2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html) contain several useful static methods to detect `Collider`s and `Collider2D`s within geometric shapes. For example, if you want to get all objects overlapping a sphere with radius 10 around the current gameObject you would do this:

```
 var colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 10f)
 foreach(var collider in colliders) {
       Debug.Log($"{collider.gameObject.name} is nearby");
 }
```

Most of these methods also have "NonAlloc" variants which overwrite an existing array instead of creating a new one. These methods are faster and generate no garbage (especially if you call them a lot), but are a bit harder to use and require that you know an upper limit of how many objects you are going to detect at most.

Comment: OP said they "cannot use [...] components". Since Colliders *are* components, this solution doesn't solve the problem as it's currently stated.

Comment: @liggiorgio Asking how to run code in Unity without using _any_ components is like asking how to build a car without using any tools. This isn't [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/); we're supposed to be answering _practical_ questions.

Comment: @Kevin I totally agree with you, we're supposed to be answering *practical* questions. But this question has never been about an actual problem [in the first place](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201340/how-to-detect-objects-within-a-radius-without-using-a-trigger-collider/201342?noredirect=1#comment366084_201340).

Comment: @liggiorgio It will be something similar but instead maybe using FindObjectsOfType and comparing positions.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the comments claiming this is an unnecessary or impractical thing to do in Unity, it's something I've had to do multiple times. In fact, just next month I'll be helping to exhibit a digital media art installation built in Unity as part of a student project that relies on this technique:

[image: Photo of "Daily Chorus" exhibited at York University, April 2022]

In this example, we were displaying a dynamic point cloud sourced from keywords in a Twitter feed. We had hundreds to low thousands of points to display and animate at a time, so having a separate GameObject and physics components acting on every one would have been a major performance draw.

Fortunately, there are lighter-weight ways to do that, even without resorting to Unity's ECS and job system (though I'd still probably advise using that route for production purposes once the system is stable).

The basic technique involves storing your "objects" not as GameObjects, but conventional C# objects or struct values in a big list or array.

When it comes time to display those objects, [you can use a particle system as shown here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/200245/39518) (or a more modern solution would be to push the points to a VFX Graph), copying the important rendering information about your non-GameObject-objects into a buffer that the built-in systems can render efficiently in a big batch.

But I'm getting a bit off-track justifying why this is a problem solvable and worth solving in Unity. Now let's get to how you solve it, which can range from dirt simple to highly engineered, depending on your performance requirements.

In the example above, we modelled spring forces between the points in the cloud, so they'd spread out and interact rather than just drift randomly. To do that, we had a position and velocity member for each point data structure, and we needed to find all pairs close enough to each other to attract/repel. The naive way to do that is something like:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++) {
    var thisObject = objects[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < objects.Count; j++) {
        var thatObject = objects[j].position;
        var difference = thisObject.position - thatObject.position;
        if (difference.magnitude < effectRadius) {
            thisObject.velocity += ComputeSpringEffect(difference);
        }
    }
    // Write the modified struct back into the list.
    objects[i] = thisObject;
}
```

But there are a couple of ways we can make this more efficient. We can check each pair just once instead of twice, and avoid an expensive square root in the radius check:

```cs
float radiusSquared = effectRadius * effectRadius;

for (int i = 1; i < objects.Count; i++) {
    var thisObject = objects[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        var thatObject = objects[j].position;
        var difference = thisObject.position - thatObject.position;
        if (difference.sqrMagnitude < radiusSquared) {
            Vector3 push = ComputeSpringEffect(difference);
            thisObject.velocity += push;
            thatObject.velocity -= push;
            objects[j] = thatObject;
        }
    }
    objects[i] = thisObject;
}
```

This is still \$O(n^2)\$, but about half the work as the naive version, and in practice a version of this was plenty to keep the installation running at high framerates. You might find it's all you need if the objects whose radii you're checking number in the hundreds to low thousands.

If you need to scale this up to tens of thousands of objects, or you have a more performance-intensive game and can't spare as much frame budget for these radius tests, then your next strategy should be to use an acceleration data structure called a [spatial partition](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/spatial-partition.html). The idea is to organize your object storage in such a way that it's fast to look up objects likely to be "nearby", without visiting every object in the list to check. That reduces your big-O complexity from \$O(n^2)\$ to something like \$O(n \times b)\$ where "b" is the number of items in each bin of the partition or \$O(n + log (n) \times c)\$ where "c" is the number of objects "close enough" to be returned - much smaller numbers, generally. These have been well documented elsewhere, so I won't go into great detail here, just note a few common search terms you can use:

- Spatial Hashing
- Quadtree / Octree
- Binary Space Partition (BSP)
- KD Tree

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution to the problem, this script helps to search for components within a radius, as well as the nearest and farthest of them https://github.com/Delmas237/VersatileUnityTools/tree/main/ComponentSearcher

Comment: Please edit this answer so the relevant code is present in the body of the post itself, not only in an external link that can rot or change independent of this answer. This ensures the answer remains useful well into the future, no matter what happens to the linked repository. It's great to use links to give credit to sources or provide further reading, but the answer should always be able to stand on its own without them.

Answer (score -2):

You should use a quadtree/Octree or Bounding Volume Hierarchy

https://github.com/Nition/UnityOctree
https://github.com/rossborchers/UnityBoundingVolumeHeirachy

Comment: Can you add an example how you would do that in the Unity game engine?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/107576)

Comment: @Philipp added links

Comment: Sorry, but just dumping links isn't sufficient for a proper answer on Stack Exchange. Answers should answer the question themselves, not post links to where an answer can be found. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on stack exchange meta for details.